# Why does using <() in a shell script cause a syntax error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script called `myShellScript.sh` inside of which I have the following text:

```
echo *** Print out this line ****
diff <(./myProgram) <(./otherProgram)
```

However, when I run `sh myShellScript.sh` I get the following error:

```
-bash-4.2$ sh myShellScript.sh 
myShellScript.sh **** Print out this line **** myShellScript.sh
myShellScript.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
myShellScript.sh: line 2: `diff <(./myProgram) <(./otherProgram)'
```

Comment: does just running "./myShellScript.sh" give you the error?

Comment: FYI, `echo *** Print out this line ***` won't always do what you want either, as the `*`s can be replaced with filenames. `echo "*** Print out this line ***"` is safer.

Comment: @TritonMan, since no shebang is specified, behavior there isn't guaranteed to be bash either. Starting the script with `#!/bin/bash` would help there.

Comment: ...by the way, for many use cases, `diff` is overkill; if you're just looking for added and removed lines and can sort your inputs, you might look at `comm` instead, which will (for the limited set of inputs it handles) operate far more efficiently.

Comment: By the way, you should quote the `***` to avoid it being treated as a pattern and expanding to a list of file names.

Comment: (as another aside -- using a `.sh` extension is somewhat bad form; it means that callers need to hardcode the language of your script, and means that either all the scripts that use yours will need to be changed or the extension will become misleading if the implementation is ever changed; finally, it hints to POSIX sh compatibility, but many/most bash scripts are _not_ compatible with POSIX sh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process substitution with the `<(...)` operator is a `bash` feature. You're getting that error message because your script is getting executed as something else (for example `dash`), or an older version of `bash`, or `bash` running in POSIX-compatibility mode with non-POSIX features like process substitution disabled (thanks, [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)!)

If you want to execute the script with a full-featured bash, you have two options:

1. Run the script with `bash`:

   ```
   bash myShellScript.sh
   ```
2. Set the first line of the script to `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever is the path to `bash` in your system), and run the script like this:

   ```
   ./myShellScript.sh
   ```

Comment: Even if `sh` *is* a link to `bash`, `bash` will run in a POSIX-compatibility mode when invoke as `sh`, disabling non-POSIX features such as process substitution.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I tidied up my post a bit

Comment: @janos how do I find the link to my bash in my system? Thanks!

Comment: You can try these commands to find it: `which bash`, or `locate bin/bash`, or if all else fails then `find / -type f -name bash`

Comment: @janos thanks. When I run bash myShellScript.sh it works well. However, when I add the path to my bash, which is /usr/bin/bash, to the top of myShellScript.sh and then try to call ./myShellScript.sh, first of all it won't auto-complete so I have to type out the full filename, and second it prints -bash: ./myShellScript.sh: Permission denied

Comment: @Apollo: In that case you need to make the script executable with something like `chmod +x myShellScript.sh`

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute your script with bash, not with sh.

You are using process substitution, which is not a standard POSIX shell feature. `sh` is a POSIX-compatible shell, so it does not support language extensions like process substitution. Bash will run with POSIX compatibility enabled if it is invoked as `sh`.

Therefore, you should execute scripts that require Bash-specific features using `bash`.

Comment: Entirely correct, but incomplete; -1 for not including any explanation.

Comment: Was actually writing the explanation. Internet cut out. I lost my post; just finishing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You clearly seem to be using `bash`, but for anyone reading this that needs to use a shell without support for process substitution, you can use the following:

```
# Instead of diff <(./myProgram) <(./otherProgram)

# A pair of named pipes to avoid using disk space
# for the output of myProgram and otherProgram
mkfifo myProgram.output
mkfifo otherProgram.output

./myProgram > myProgram.output &
./otherProgram > otherProgram.output &

diff myProgram.output otherProgram.output

rm myProgram.output otherProgram.output
```

This is nearly identical to how `bash` might perform process substitution on some platforms.